# Kendo Treeview - Add class to treeItem <li> element in kendo treeView

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I am trying to distinguish between a folder and a leaf in kendo treeView, so I will do different css classes for each type.

```
<li role="treeitem" class="k-item k-first blalala" data-uid="1111"data-expanded="true">
```

I want to add the "blalala" class only to leaf nodes.
I tried doing something in the dataBound function, but I don't know how to distinguish it in the jquery / htmlElement. The following code adding this class to all elements with class "k-item"

```
        const treeViewOptions: kendo.ui.TreeViewOptions = {
        dataBound: (e: kendo.ui.TreeViewDataBoundEvent): void => {

            const treeItem = $('.k-item:not(:has(.k-item))');
            if (treeItem) {
                treeItem.addClass("blalala");
            }

        },}
```

I found an example of a tree so you can try to help me: [example](http://jsbin.com/igirur/10/edit)

Comment: Whats the difference between a folder and a leaf node?

Comment: In leaf there are no children (also children that are not direct) with 'k-item' class on it. So, I tried using this `$('.k-item:not(:has(.k-item))');` but this isn't work. (It's catch also folders that have non direct children with 'k-item' class on it). Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Rog, Check the answer and demo.

Answer (score 1):

In such case we can handle the [dataBound](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/events/databound) event separately for the root items and for the child items and add the custom class by using [findByUid](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/treeview/methods/findbyuid) method depending on the hasChildren property. Here is a [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/@zdravkov/UjIhASEL) and the code that I used:

```
 <div class="demo-section k-content">
            <h4>Inline data (default settings)</h4>
            <div id="treeview-left"></div>
        </div>

        <script>
            var inlineDefault = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
                data: [
                    { text: "Furniture", items: [
                        { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                        { text: "Sofas" },
                        { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                    ] },
                    { text: "Decor", items: [
                        { text: "Bed Linen" },
                        { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                        { text: "Carpets" }
                    ] }
                ]
            });

            var addClass = function (treeview, items){

                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                                            if(!items[i].hasChildren){
                        treeview.findByUid(items[i].uid).addClass('blalalala')
                    }
                            }
            }

            $("#treeview-left").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: inlineDefault,
                loadOnDemand: false,
                dataBound: function(e){

                     if (!e.node) {
                      var rootItems = e.sender.dataSource.data();
                      addClass(e.sender, rootItems);
                   } else {
                        var rootItem = e.sender.dataItem(e.node);

                      var subItems = rootItem.children.data();
                      addClass(e.sender, subItems);

                             }
                }
            });


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over all the `li` nodes and check if it has children and add the class.

```js
$("#treeview").kendoTreeView({

    dataSource: [{
        text: "My Documents",
        expanded: true,
        items: [{
                text: "Kendo UI Project",
                expanded: true,
                items: [{
                        text: "about.html"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "index.html"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "logo.png"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "New Web Site",
                expanded: true,
                items: [{
                        text: "mockup.jpg"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "Research.pdf"
                    },
                ]
            },
            {
                text: "Reports",
                expanded: true,
                items: [{
                        text: "February.pdf"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "March.pdf"
                    },
                    {
                        text: "April.pdf"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }]
});
var treeview = $("#treeview").data("kendoTreeView");
$.each($('#treeview li'), function() {
    var node = treeview.dataItem($(this));
    if (node.hasChildren) {
        $(this).find('.k-in').addClass('folder');

    } else
        $(this).find('.k-in').addClass('leaf');
});
```

```css
.folder { color:green; }
.leaf { color:red; }
```

```html
<head>
<title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2018.2.516/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="treeview"></div>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Per my vue.js project, I just added styles based on the generated DOM hierarchy

```
<style>
/* root item class */
div > ul > li > div > span.k-in {
  color: black !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 105%;
}
/* level 2 child item class */
div > ul > li > ul > li > div > span.k-in  {
  color: #284d8e !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 100%;
}
/* level 3 child item class */
div > ul > li > ul > li > ul > li > div > span.k-in  {
  color: black !important;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
} 
</style>
```